# Como puedo parar (poner stop) a un evento de localizacion en android?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Buenas noches muchas gracias por responder, me gustaria saber como hago para que solo 1 vez ocurra ese evento ok me refiero al evento de AddOnSuccessListener ok aqui les pongo el codigo.

```
   mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
            .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
                @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(Location location) {
                    //Sabiendo que obtuvimos location, lo usamos
                    if (location != null) {
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Latitud: " +location.getLatitude() + "Longitud: " + location.getLongitude(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                         tvlocation.setText(""+location.getAltitude()+" "+location.getLongitude());

                    }
                }
            });
```

mire segun tengo entendido ese evento addOnSuccessListener ocurrira cada vez se encuentre o suceda una nueva localizacion, pues yo quiero que ese evento ocurra una vez , pues esta en el oncreate del activity principal captara la localizacion pero hasta ahi no mas esa sera la ultima despues ya no quiero mas como seria?. muchas gracias.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

El evento `addOnSuccessListener` solo se dispara cuando [getLastLocation()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient#getLastLocation()) encuentra valores para retornar, de esa forma `addOnSuccessListener` solo escucha a que el valor que devuelve de tipo Task [getLastLocation()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient#getLastLocation()) no sea null para poder darnos en onSuccess los valores del tipo Location.

Este codigo se ejecuta solo una vez y no esta escuchando todo el tiempo por cambios, podes moverte y ejecutar de nuevo el codigo que te actualizaria la ubicacion.

Lo que si actualiza todo el tiempo es un [onLocationChange](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html#onLocationChanged(android.location.Location)) , este si va a escuchar cuando cambies de posicion y darte los valores cada vez que los hagas(pasandole antes algunos parametros para que se actualize)

Traduciendo la documentacion de [getLastLocation()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/FusedLocationProviderClient#getLastLocation()) podes asegurarte que no actualiza todo el tiempo con lo siguiente

> Si una ubicación no está disponible, lo que debería ocurrir muy
>   raramente, se devolverá un valor nulo. Se devolverá la mejor precisión
>   disponible respetando los permisos de ubicación.
>
> Este método proporciona una forma simplificada de obtener ubicación.
>   Es especialmente adecuado para aplicaciones que no requieren una
>   ubicación precisa y que no desean mantener una lógica adicional para
>   las actualizaciones de ubicación.

Answer (score 1):

Declaramos una variable de tipo shared preference:

```
SharedPreferences preferencias = getSharedPreferences("Preferencias", MODE_PRIVATE); 

 mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation() 
 .addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<Location>() {
  @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
  @Override 
 public void onSuccess(Location location) { //Sabiendo que obtuvimos location, lo usamos

 boolean noRepetir = preferencias.getBoolean("noRepetir", false);

 if (!noRepetir){
 if (location != null) { 

 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Latitud: " +location.getLatitude() + "Longitud: " + location.getLongitude(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  tvlocation.setText(""+location.getAltitude()+" "+location.getLongitude()); 

 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences("Preferencias", MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
 editor.putBoolean("noRepetir", true);
 editor.apply();
        } 
    }
 }
 });
```

Bueno ya es un poquito mas complicado. Ahora declaramos un SharedPreference llamado **preferencias** esto nos servirá para guardar y acceder a datos guardados como datos de la aplicación, pues para que se entienda el funcionamiento en la variable **preferencias** le digo getsharedpreference y le paso un nombre y un contexto que es int el nombre sera el nombre del contenedor de nuestro datos y el contexto entero es el tipo de acceso el cual solo debes usar private, luego de creado vez que debajo de tu código cree una variable **editor** esta edita las preferencias, luego le digo que establezca un bool y le paso como parametros nombre y valor de ese campo el nombre que utilize es *noRepetir* y el valor es *true* y luego llamo a aplicar esa edición, en otras palabras aqui guardo un valor booleano dentro de el contenedor **preferencias** dentro del campo llamado *noRepetir* y lo establezco en verdadero.

Esto es lo que nos servirá: `boolean noRepetir = preferencias.getBoolean("noRepetir", false);` si vas un poco mas arriba te encuentras con ese código. En este declaro una variable booleana **noRepetir** y esta obtendra el valor que esta en el contenedor **preferencias** en el campo *noRepetir* y como ves recibe 2 parametros (nombre, valor por defecto) el nombre es el nombre del campo es decir *noRepetir* y el valor por defecto es el valor que se establece si el campo no existe o no contiene ningún valor.

Luego de haber obtenido ese valor en nuestra variable preguntamos que si es falsa se ejecute el codigo.

Esto debería funcionar de la siguiente manera la primera vez que inicia la actividad el campo *noRepetir* no tendra valor asignado por lo que por defecto se ejecutara el codigo en el cual tambien se cambiara el valor de noRepetir es decir guardaremos un valor en ese campo por lo que cuuando se vuelva a tratar de ejecutar el codigo **noRepetir** sera *true* por lo que no se ejecutara nunca mas al menos que borres el campo dentro de tus preferencias.

Esto lo utilizo para apps que requieren que se inicie sesión y establezco que inicie sesión solo una vez o hasta que cierre la sesión por lo que no tiene porque estar llenando el formulario cada vez que entre.

Comment: Te entiendo amigo , entopnces si noRepetir la declaro fuera de onCreate obviamente dentro de la clase MainActivity , abajo pa ser mas especifico, entonces si hago eso aunq el usuario cierre la aplicacion y vuelva a entrar ya no tendria q ejecutarse ese evento verdad? porque mi idea esq se ejecute solo 1 vez y nada mas despues aunq cierre la aplicacion o la reinicie no vuelva a llamarse , a no ser q la desintale y vuelva a instalar ahi si que se llame.

Comment: Ok cambiare el codigo pues este no funcionara de esa manera

Comment: Gracias amigo :).-

Answer (score 1):

Desde mi punto de vista lo mejor en tu caso seria hacer lo siguiente en la interfaz que detecta la nueva localización llamar al metodo que desconecta y remueve el listener te dejo esta clase que aun esta en construcción pero funciona correctamente, en ella se remueve el LocationUpdate al encontrar
la localización, echa un vistazo espero te funcione.

```
public class GoogleProviderLocation extends FusedLocationProviderClient{


GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
Location mLastLocation;
FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
LocationCallback mLocationCallback;
Context context;
Activity activity;
GoogleLocationListener listener;

{
     mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
            List<Location> locationList = locationResult.getLocations();
            if (locationList.size() > 0) {
                //The last location in the list is the newest
                Location location = locationList.get(locationList.size() - 1);
                Log.i("GoogleProviderLocation", "Location: " + location.getLatitude() + " " + location.getLongitude());
                mLastLocation = location;
                listener.OnLocationFound(location);
                disconnect();
                //Place current location marker
                LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

                //move map camera
                mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 11));
            }
        }
    };
}


public GoogleProviderLocation(@NonNull Context context,GoogleLocationListener listener,GoogleMap map) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    this.listener = listener;
    this.mGoogleMap =map;
    Connect();
    Log.i("GoogleProviderLocation",mFusedLocationClient.toString());
}

public GoogleProviderLocation(@NonNull Activity activity,GoogleLocationListener listener) {
    super(activity);
    this.activity = activity;
    this.listener = listener;
    Connect();
}



@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
public void Connect(){
    mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(context);
    if (mFusedLocationClient!=null)
        Log.i("Connected(): ",mFusedLocationClient.toString());

    Log.i("onMapReady() : "," "+mGoogleMap.getCameraPosition());

    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(120000); // two minute interval
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(120000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY);

    mFusedLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, mLocationCallback, Looper.myLooper());
    mGoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

}

public void disconnect(){
    if (mFusedLocationClient != null) {
        mFusedLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(mLocationCallback);
        Log.i("disconnected(): ",mFusedLocationClient.toString());
    }
}

public interface GoogleLocationListener{
    void OnLocationFound(Location location);
}
```

}

Este listener **GoogleLocationListener** es para retornar el valor a la actividad que necesite los datos de la ubicación.